# Infinite loop on element focus

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
  $("body").on("focus", ".input", function () {
      $("body").append("loop<br>");
      $(this).find("input").focus();
  });
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Hc3D8/

Why does it loop?

Comment: check the fiddle please.

Comment: explain what you are trying to do

Comment: when I focus the wrapper, move the focus to the inner input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It loops because you are attaching a function to the `focus` event, which itself triggers a `focus` event.

Even though you call the `focus` event on the inner `input` element, it still bubbles to the outer `.input` element.

To workaround this you could hook to a different event on the outer element:

```
$("body").on("click", ".input", function () { // click event
    $("body").append("loop<br>");
    $(this).find("input").focus();
});
```

Or you could stop propagation on the `focus` of the `input`:

```
$("body")
    .on("focus", ".input", function () {
        $("body").append("loop<br>");
        $(this).find("input").focus();
    })
    .on('focus', 'input', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hc3D8/2/)

Comment: So how can I focus the input field inside the .input div when I focus on the div?

Comment: Use a different event on the `.input` element - possibly `click`.

Comment: @FezVrasta you just need to call `e.stopPropagation()` on the `focus` event for the `input`.  See my answer for an updated working solution

Comment: Thanks it works, but I've solved using as selector an `.input:not(.focus)`, just because I already add the `.focus` class when the element is focused, but your example is better if you don't have a class added.

Answer (score 2):

It loops because you called `.focus()` on the element again inside the event handler, which triggers the `focus` event on the same element and thus fires the event handler over again causing it to loop forever.

Just remove `$(this).find("input").focus();`

**EDIT:** to stop event propagation (and prevent the `focus` on `input` bubbling up the DOM to `.input` and causing the loop) change your code to this:

```
  $("body").on("focus", ".input", function () {
      $("body").append("loop<br>");
      $(this).find("input").focus(function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); } );
  });
```

[**Updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hc3D8/1/)

Comment: I call focus on `input`, not on `.input`

Comment: @FezVrasta that is due to event propagation. Your `input` element is inside the `.input` element which means the `focus` event on `input` bubbles up the DOM to the `.input` as well.

Comment: @FezVrasta Updated my answer with a working solution

Comment: You are attaching a `focus` event handler, not calling `focus` on the `input`

Comment: @FezVrasta Exactly my point - that is what the OP wants to do

Comment: @FezVrasta You're exactly right, I'm sorry!  I misunderstood what you were trying to accomplish here.  The solution Rory provided works as you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Because this finds the input in body and focus it and call this focus event again .
So it is infinite loop.

```
$("body").on("focus", ".input", function () {
    $("body").append("loop<br>");
    $(this).find("input").focus(); //this finds the input in body and focus it and call this function again 
});
```

remove `$(this).find("input").focus();`

```
$("body").on("focus", ".input", function () {
    $("body").append("loop<br>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It loops because of your last line in the code:

```
$(this).find("input").focus();
```

So, since it have an attached event to run with focus, it'll loop.

Answer (score 0):

IE,Safari,Opera,Firefox are not creating such issue but chrome is giving this issue. so tackle it we have to use some trick.
I am providing my own solution , i.e. 
I used button with visibility false and on focus out event at end of focus out trying to click that button so it got solved. like wise i got workaround it.

another solution 
user alert statement to solve it.